# Firmar documento XML con metodo de firma sha256

Tags: c#, xml

Desarrollo una aplicacion que firma un documento XML..hasta alli perfecto...

Pero debo cambiar esta linea de la firma

```
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
```

por esta otra :

```
   <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha256"/>
```

Mi codigo:

```
public void MainFirma (string path)
    {
        try
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY";
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load(path);
            SignXml(xmlDoc, rsaKey);
            xmlDoc.Save(path);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public  void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc, RSA rsaKey)
    {
        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("xmlDoc");
        if (rsaKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Key");

        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
        signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;

        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(env);
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

    }
```

Esta es la firma que genera

```
-<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">


-<SignedInfo>

<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>

<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>


-<Reference URI="">


-<Transforms>

<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>

</Transforms>

<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>

<DigestValue>5t5A+HP9r0xCuKg1FeZCHs0KFWc=</DigestValue>

</Reference>

</SignedInfo>

<SignatureValue>AynCAsWd+Y3uMma2ObaR+2GFei9WCpH00RZ5cKW1JD34zPqLBa6nL9PBAr6yrnPIWAKnFe/ndIDH+Z6ooQCjDDjdWtYRPjgRVFMRVMGW7CSsgpXlX+LDvCX5fGFKL1fwQH5qrW1bWlHObr+BZ8B1o7LpqJ/lp8STxNUD0elAIgI=</SignatureValue>

</Signature>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando dices que quieres:

```
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha256"/>
```

Me imagino que la parte importante es que se usa `SHA256` en vez de `SHA1`, porque, estrictamente hablando, ese URL no es válido. El correcto es:

```
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
```

En mis pruebas, solo necesito agregar una sentencia a tu código para hacer el cambio:

```
SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;

// agrega este sentencia aquí.
signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
```

---

Y aunque no lo pedistes, tal vez desees cambiar el algoritmo para el digest a SHA256 también:

```
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
```

Para esto necesitas otra sentencia más:

```
reference.AddTransform(env);

// agrega este sentencia aquí.
reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";

signedXml.AddReference(reference);
```